# How can I get Python to look for pip installed packages before apt-get installed packages?

Tags: python, pip, package, python-import, apt-get

When I install packages with pip, they get placed into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. When I install with apt-get, they get installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.

I accidentally installed a package with apt-get that was already installed with pip (I assume apt-get saw this package as necessary for something else I was installing with apt-get) and now the apt-get version is preferentially used instead of the pip version.

How can I reverse this situation? How do I get Python to look for packages that are installed by pip (i.e. the most recent version) before it looks for packages installed via apt-get (i.e. the latest version approved by Debian/Ubuntu)?

I don't want to be in a position of needing to make many ad-hoc changes to a PYTHONPATH variable or, somehow, to my sys.path.

Comment: What Python and OS are you using?  On my Python 2.7.6 installation on Ubuntu Trusty, `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` comes before `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` in `sys.path` (which I haven't explicitly touched), so pip packages are preferred to apt-get packages.

Comment: i think you should always use a virtualenv for a specific project to not have this kind of problems.

Comment: @arcticless - You're right. I'm afraid I'm somewhat sadder & wiser now

Comment: @jwodder - I'm using Ubuntu Trusty, & Python 2.7.8 (I believe - I'll have to get back to the actual machine to be certain). I do know that when I change sys.path for a given instatntiation of the python interpreter, using sys.path.insert, I can force the importation of a particular pip package, instead of the apt-get package. In my case numpy_1.10 instead of numpy_1.8.